# Change CSS if URL has hash

Tags: jquery, css, hash

I'm trying to change an element's CSS when the URL has a hash in it.
The URL looks like

```
http://foo.com/base/something#item-itemID
```

The only static part in the URL is the **#item-** bit. The **something** and the **itemID** bits change. So whenever a URL has **#item** (dash omitted on purpose) in it I'd like to change

```
<ul class="side">
```

into

```
<ul class="side hashed">
```

After creating a specific class for this case I managed to compile a piece of JS code based on my poor understanding of JS and JQuery to add this class to the element:

```
$(function() {
  var loc = window.location.hash;
  if(/^#item/.test(loc)) {
    $('ul.side').addClass('hashed');
  }
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Please help.
Any suggestions in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should debug this step by step: First, check if the the `var loc` really contains the URL you want, then check if the regex really works... Btw the .test-method looks strange

Comment: Wait a minute!!!!! what are you really trying to do? will the # actually be targeting a specific element with an id, for example, `<li id="item-itemID">`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (window.location.hash.split('-')[0] == '#item') {
    $('ul.side').addClass('hashed');
}
```

Comment: No errors, but no effect either. Tried loading the script in <head> and in the footer.

Comment: Replacing **$('ul.side').addClass('hashed');** with **console.log("found");** outputs **found** into the console. So the first line works, the hash is detected correctly, but the class isn't added for some reason...

Comment: My bad. Was loading jQuery in no-conflict mode, thus the syntax error.  
Thanks for the answer, @6ahodir !

Answer (score 2):

A pure CSS solution ([demo](http://jsbin.com/acuvov/1/))

```
a[href*="#"] {  
  color: purple; /* contains a hash */  
}
```

This will even work on IE7 ;)

This is just the selector, the CSS attributes you'd put in there are whatever values .hashed already has.

Comment: OP is looking for the current document URL and not a link's href.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. I thought `.side a[href*="#"] {...}` was exactly what was needed. Gotcha.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I had in mind. Fabrício is right.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    var loc = (window.location.hash).split("-");

    if (loc[0] == "#item") {
        console.log("item found");
        //  $('ul.side').addClass('hashed');
    }
});
```

**EDIT: change responsive functionality**

Thanks for checking it out. I do not have the error you describe in the comments when committing an isolated test. I did see inconsistencies that may be an issue to the responsiveness. Your code snippet does not look for a hash change, so I adapted it to look for a hash upon page load and also trigger when it gets changed dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/hqdvC/

```
$(function () {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        getHash();
    }
    $(window).on("hashchange", function () {
        getHash();
    });
});

function getHash() {
    var loc = (window.location.hash).split("-");
    if (loc[0] == "#item") {
        console.log("item found");
        //  $('ul.side').addClass('hashed');
    };
}
```

There is some odd behavior. When you have a hash in the url and highlight the address bar and hit enter, the page does not refresh. I searched for an answer but there is nothing I could find. Baffled by this I started my own question: [Page refresh from address bar with #hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403908/page-refresh-from-address-bar-with-hash)

Comment: The console only throws an error:  
_Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function (anonymous function)_

Comment: @PauloFino - I added some information to the answer. I did not see the error you refer to. The script acts under jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This way uses PHP to check if the url contains a hash and then if this is the case, you can amend your css however you wish.

```
<?php

     $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
     $hash = '-';   
     $hashurl = strpos($url, $hash);

     if ($hashurl !== false) {

     echo '

         //add jquery to add and/or remove css class to element.        

     ';

     }

?>
```