# Page refresh from address bar with #hash

Tags: javascript, page-refresh, hashtag

Situation:

url: http://mydomain.com/test.html#somehash

test script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("page initiated");
    if (window.location.hash) {
        console.log("hash changed (if-statement)");
    }

    $(window).on("hashchange", function () {
        console.log("hash changed (on statement)");
    });

});
```

The script can also be found on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/dcVu8/2/), but the environment is not suitable to display the behavior.

The problem I get is when I click on the browser addressbar and hit enter without any changes.

1. When the browser url has a hashtag, the page is not re-initiated. `document.ready` does not get fired and I do not get any console messages.
2. When the browser url does not have a hashtag, the page does get re-initiated and `document.ready` is fired.

Does anybody have an explanation for this behavior and can it be caught so that in situation 1 the page does get reloaded?
Is there documentation somewhere, because I can't seem to find any?

Comment: This is desired behaviour. If your URL contains a hash string, it's not supposed to initiate a full page refresh.

Comment: I was kind of struck. Is this documented somewhere? Is there a specific reason to render this as desired behavior? When I click the "refresh" button on the browser menu, I have a normal refresh.

Comment: Adding a hash to a URL indicates you mean to navigate within the page, not navigate to a new page. Clicking the "refresh" button indicates you want to re-request the document. Pressing enter on the URL bar and clicking refresh are very different things.

Comment: @meager - thanks for your input. I suppose the "navigation inside the page" clears it up for me. Especially when doing my programming i may refresh with the above scenario expecting a page refresh. Good to be aware of this.

Comment: @meager - could you add an answer or tell me otherwise how I can close this question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is desired behaviour. If your URL contains a hash string, it's not supposed to initiate a full page refresh.

Adding a hash to a URL indicates you mean to navigate within the page, not navigate to a new page. Clicking the "refresh" button indicates you want to re-request the document. Pressing enter on the URL bar and clicking refresh are very different things.